# Stock Graph in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, graph

I am working with Graph application.In it I have to implement Stock Graphs for fatching datas via webservice.So would you suggest me about any impressive SDK or API for Graphs in Iphon/Ipad.I was trying with Roambi but I dont think its more useful.I used Core plot Library and Categoty Line Graphs.But is there other way for that instead of this?So please would you suggest me?

Comment: I'd say you named the most important once already, if those don't suffice you should consider writing one yourself. You may also go for a javascript lib and render your graphs in a webiew. You could even render those off screen and take a screenshot of it if you don't want to present the user a webiew.

Comment: I want to make Stock graph as describe in iphon's default utility as its name describe Stock.

Comment: Try looking at OpenGL es for simple shape rendering.  OpenGL FTW...

Comment: Thanks for reply I am trying with this..

Answer (score 3):

Did you look inside the Core Plot framework to see the sample applications that ship with it?  The AAPLot sample application is a stock charting application that mimics the style of Apple's built-in Stocks application (with a few additions, like volume charting and trading ranges):

[image]
<sub>(source: [sunsetlakesoftware.com](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AAPlot.jpg))</sub>

Core Plot even has a theme called `kCPStocksTheme` that does this exact style.  I don't know how much easier it can get than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@interface DueDate : UITableViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,EKEventEditViewDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>{

    EKEventViewController *detailViewController;
    EKEventStore *eventStore;
    EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;

    NSMutableArray *eventsList;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) EKEventViewController *detailViewController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@property (nonatomic,retain) EKCalendar *defaultCalendar;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *eventsList;

-(NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday;
- (IBAction) addEvent:(id)sender;

@end



#import "DueDate.h"


@implementation DueDate
@synthesize detailViewController,eventStore,defaultCalendar,eventsList;

- (void)dealloc {
    [eventStore release];
    [eventsList release];
    [defaultCalendar release];
    [detailViewController release];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.title = @"Remind Me";

    self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    self.eventsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:0];

    self.defaultCalendar = [self.eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addEvent:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButtonItem;
    [addButtonItem release];

    self.navigationController.delegate = self;

    [self.eventsList addObjectsFromArray:[self fetchEventsForToday]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload{
    self.eventsList = nil;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:NO];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday{
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];

    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray];

    NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    return events;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [eventsList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCellAccessoryType editableCellAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];        
    }

    cell.accessoryType = editableCellAccessoryType;

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];

    return cell;    
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.detailViewController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.event = [self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailViewController.allowsEditing = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (viewController == self && self.detailViewController.event.title == NULL) {
        [self.eventsList removeObject:self.detailViewController.event];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action{

    NSError *error = nil;
    EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;

    switch (action) {
        case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
             break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
            if (self.defaultCalendar == thisEvent.calendar) {
                [self.eventsList addObject:thisEvent];
            }
            [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]; 
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
            if (self.defaultCalendar == thisEvent.calendar) {
                [self.eventsList removeObject:thisEvent];
            }
            [controller.eventStore removeEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller{
    EKCalendar *calendarForEdit = self.defaultCalendar;
    return calendarForEdit;
}

- (void) addEvent:(id)sender{
    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
//    [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

    addController.editViewDelegate = self;
    [addController release];
}



@end




#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HomePageWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;
    NSURL *contenturl;
}
-(void)setNavigationTitle:(NSString *)title;
-(void)setURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end


#import "HomePageWebViewController.h"


@implementation HomePageWebViewController
-(void)setURL:(NSURL *)url{
    contenturl = url;
}
-(void)setNavigationTitle:(NSString *)title{
    self.title = title;
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark WEBVIEW DELEGATE

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:contenturl]];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if([webView isLoading]){
        [webView stopLoading];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>



@interface MainMenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

    NSMutableArray *aryProfessions;
    NSMutableArray *aryMainMenuItems;
//    NSMutableArray *barItems;

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pkrProfession;
    IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnDone;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel;

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller;

    NSInteger _selIndex;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selIndex;

- (IBAction)selectAnItem:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)itemNotSelected:(id)sender;


@end


#import "MainMenuViewController.h"
#import "HomePageWebViewController.h"
#import "DueDate.h"


@implementation MainMenuViewController
@synthesize selIndex = _selIndex;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.title = @"ChiroCredit Main Menu";




    [pkrProfession setHidden:YES];
    [toolBar setHidden:YES];
    [btnDone setEnabled:NO];



    aryMainMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ChiroCredit Home Page",@"Countinuing Education Courses",@"Continuing Education FAQ's",@"Contact US",@"Remind me when Credits are Due",nil];

    aryProfessions = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Please Select Anyone Course",
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Aromatherapy",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=27",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Athletic Trainer",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=14",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Boundary Training",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=25",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chiropractic Assistant",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=3",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chiropractic Doctor",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=1",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chiropractic Student",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=2",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hand Therapist",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=4",@"url",nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Holistic Health Counselor",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=28",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Legal Secretary/Word Processor",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=34",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Massage Therapy",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=22",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Medical Doctor",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=32",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Naturopath",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=24",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Nursing",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=26",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Occupational Therapist",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=19",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"OT Assistant",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=21",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Other Florida Professionals",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=35",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Physical Therapist",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=18",@"url", nil],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"PT Assistant",@"title",@"http://www.chirocredit.com/courses/index.php?action=Show+Topics&pid=20",@"url", nil],
                       nil] retain];
    NSLog(@"array count is:- %i",[aryProfessions count]);
//    [pkrProfession reloadComponent:0];
    [self.view reloadInputViews];
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [aryMainMenuItems count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [aryMainMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        HomePageWebViewController *objHomePage = [[HomePageWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageWebViewController" bundle:nil];
        [objHomePage setNavigationTitle:@"ChiroCredit"];
        [objHomePage setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.chirocredit.com/"]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objHomePage animated:YES];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        [toolBar setHidden:NO];
//        barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//        
//        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 0)];
//        [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
//        NSString *strLabel = @"Please Select any one course";
//        lbl.text=strLabel;
//        lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
//        
//        UIBarButtonItem *lblBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:lbl];
//        [lbl release];
//        
//        [barItems addObject:btnCancel];
//        [barItems addObject:lblBtn];
//        [barItems addObject:btnDone];
//        [toolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
//        [toolBar addSubview:lbl];
        [pkrProfession setHidden:NO];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        HomePageWebViewController *objHomePage = [[HomePageWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageWebViewController" bundle:nil];
        [objHomePage setNavigationTitle:@"Continuing Education FAQ's"];
        [objHomePage setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.chirocredit.com/pages/faqs.php"]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objHomePage animated:YES];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 3){
        NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"powers@chirocredit.com",nil];
        controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;  
        [controller setSubject:@"Contact Online CE"];
        [controller setToRecipients:array1];
        NSString *emailBody = @" ";
        [controller setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
    }
    else{
        DueDate *objDueDate = [[DueDate alloc] initWithNibName:@"DueDate" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDueDate animated:YES];
    }    
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                        error:(NSError*)error
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        NSLog(@"Mail Sent...!");

        UIAlertView *mailSend=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Sender" message:@"Mail has been sent.." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [mailSend show];
        [mailSend release];        
    }
    if (MFMailComposeResultCancelled) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

//PICKER VIEW DELEGATES....

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    return [aryProfessions count];

}



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (row==0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please Select Anyone Course"];
    }
    else{
        return [[aryProfessions objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"title"];
    }
    return nil;


}



- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (row == 0) {
        [btnDone setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else{
        [btnDone setEnabled:YES];
    }
     self.selIndex = row;
    if (self.selIndex == 0) {
        [btnDone setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else{
        [btnDone setEnabled:YES];
    }    
}

- (IBAction)selectAnItem:(id)sender {
    if (self.selIndex != 0) {
        NSDictionary *dicRow = [aryProfessions objectAtIndex:self.selIndex];
        HomePageWebViewController *objProfession = [[HomePageWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageWebViewController" bundle:nil];
        [objProfession setNavigationTitle:[dicRow objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [objProfession setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dicRow objectForKey:@"url"]]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objProfession animated:YES];
        [dicRow release];
    }

}

- (IBAction)itemNotSelected:(id)sender{
    [toolBar setHidden:YES];
    [pkrProfession setHidden:YES];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: @sinh99, this is amd's reply, i just fixed the formating of the posting so that it is displayed as code block.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [StockChartX iOS](http://www.modulusfe.com/stockchartxios/).